# Using a wifi card in virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

My objective is to use one of my spare wifi cards and run a virtual machine which will then control this wifi card.
I tried using virtual box for this purpose and kali linux but the only options available is to connect to a network using the host-device.
Is there any way for me to control to the wifi card directly to the virtual machine?

Comment: You can assign a USB WiFi card to a a VM using Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

many virtual machine admin panels offer a way to grant a virtual machine access to physical hardware.

In kvm e.g. you can add this hardware via virtmanager to the virtual machine. So the access to this host-system's hardware is permitted to the virtual machine and you should be able to use it.

[example for adding host.hardware to vm guest in virtmanager by redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/images/3_PCI_Device.png)